# How can i get the indexes of all the occurrences of an element in a list through recursion?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, recursion

I was learning recursion and stumbled upon a question. How can I get the indexes of all the occurrences of an element in a list through recursion?

**My understanding:**

1. When the index equals to the length of the array it returns the array(or should return an array of indexes)
2. The first call increments the occurrence of fsf(found_so_far) and increments the index(when the if the condition is executed)
3. the second call increments just the index idx(the else part of the condition)

**Flaws:**

1. every time the function is called a new empty list(which stores results of all occurrences of the key) is created
2. the append function doesn't  append the occurrences  to the resultant list
3. after all the calls an empty list that is called by the else part of the condition returns an empty list(post calls/backtracking)

My code:

```
def allindex(arr, idx, fsf, key):  #arr=array, idx=index, fsf=found so far, key=key to be found
    list = []
    if idx == len(arr):
        return list
    if arr[idx] == key:
        allindex(arr, idx + 1, fsf + 1, 8)
        list.append(idx)
        return list
    else:
        allindex(arr, idx + 1, fsf, 8)
        return list


arr = [2, 4, 5, 8, 1, 8, 6, 8, 7, 9]
allindex(arr, 0, 0, 8) #passes an (array,starting_index,found_so_far,key)
```

Expected output:

```
[3,5,7]
```

Got instead:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are creating a new `list` object each time you recursively call the function, since you are doing `list = []` each time. (By the way, do not name a variable `list`, it is already a reserved keyword in Python that denotes the `list` type, here you can use `indices_found` for example)

What you want to do is actually pass down the same list to every call of the function :

```py
def allindex(
    arr, idx, fsf, key, found_indices
):  # arr=array, idx=index, fsf=found so far, key=key to be found
    if idx == len(arr):
        return found_indices
    if arr[idx] == key:
        found_indices.append(idx)
        allindex(arr, idx + 1, fsf + 1, 8, found_indices)
        return found_indices
    else:
        allindex(arr, idx + 1, fsf, 8, found_indices)
        return found_indices
```

This correctly returns `[3, 5, 7]`.

Comment: one of my trial approaches was this approach that you followed, seems there is some problem with the configurations of the interpreter(it isn't working as it should). Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A basic flaw with the posted solution is:

```
list = []
```

Posted recursion always starts over with a new array which prevents solution from being accumulated.

Also, `list` is discouraged as a variable name in Python since it conflicts with builtin function.

**Working recursive function**

```
def allindex(arr, key, i = 0, indexes = None):  
    if indexes is None:
      indexes = []

    # Reached end of list (Base case)
    if i  == len(arr):
      return indexes            # no more recursion

    # Found item
    if arr[i] == key:  
      indexes.append(i)              

    # Recursive call to next index of array
    allindex(arr, key, i+1, indexes)

    return indexes

arr = [2, 4, 5, 8, 1, 8, 6, 8, 7, 9]
print(allindex(arr, 8))

Output: [3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(arr, val):
    # solve the base case
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return []

    # get  solution for arr[1:]
    res = f(arr[1:], val)

    # add one to res for correct indexing
    res = [i + 1 for i in res]

    if arr[0] == val:
        return [0] + res 
    return res
```

Comment: thank you for this clever approach(i will be sure to  learn these tricks and use them  in competitive coding), much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

You can use enumerate to select the index of specific elements.

```
arr = [2, 4, 5, 8, 1, 8, 6, 8, 7, 9]
my_number = 8

index_list =[idx for idx, el in enumerate(arr) if el == my_number]
```

Comment: IT was about how to do recursion